# Illegal Integer Character in Hexadecimal

Tags: java, int, syntax-error, byte

I am working on an encryption scheme that uses substitution boxes. I was given substitution boxes to use, in which each element in the box (saved as an array) is in hexadecimal (0xD1310BA6 for example). For some reason, I'm getting a syntax error (I am using NetBeans) that says "illegal character '\u00a0'" I don't understand what the problem really is or how to fix it. I tried changing the array type to long in case int wasn't big enough (pretty sure it is) or char since it was giving me an error about characters, but neither fixed the problem.

Here is part of one of my S-Boxes and some of the code that uses the S-Boxes so you understand what I'm trying to do with them.

S-Box:

```
final public int[] SBox1 = {
    0xD1310BA6, 0x98DFB5AC, 0x2FFD72DB, 0xD01ADFB7, 
    0xB8E1AFED, 0x6A267E96, 0xBA7C9045, 0xF12C7F99, 
    0x24A19947, 0xB3916CF7, 0x0801F2E2, 0x858EFC16, 
    0x636920D8, 0x71574E69, 0xA458FEA3, 0xF4933D7E, 
    0x0D95748F, 0x728EB658, 0x718BCD58, 0x82154AEE, 
    0x7B54A41D, 0xC25A59B5, 0x9C30D539, 0x2AF26013, 
    0xC5D1B023, 0x286085F0, 0xCA417918, 0xB8DB38EF, 
    0x8E79DCB0, 0x603A180E, 0x6C9E0E8B, 0xB01E8A3E,
};
```

Relevant Code:

```
public int Feistel(int x) {
    int f1 = SBox((byte) (x & 0xFF), 1);
    int f2 = SBox((byte) ((x >>> 8) & 0xFF), 2);
    int f3 = SBox((byte) ((x >>> 16) & 0xFF), 3);
    int f4 = SBox((byte) ((x >>> 24) & 0xFF), 4);
    return (int) ((((int) (f1 + f2 % Math.pow(2, 32)) ^ f3) + f4) % Math.pow(2, 32));
}
```

Not included is the function that will substitute the values (SBox(byte, int)) as I have not finished writing it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\u00a0 is a non-breakable space. So you can't see it in your code because it just looks like a regular space character, but it's there somewhere, in the line (and probably column) indicated by the error message.

Erase that space and replace it by a regular space character.

Comment: Haha what a stupid mistake. Damn my professor for not formatting the S-Boxes correctly. Thank you!